# fsck and checking external drives on reboot also

Tags: hard-disk, fsck, external-hdd

I know about **shutdown -rF now** that will check the drive on reboot but how can I also have it check all external drives also on reboot?

Comment: Change the pass field in /etc/fstab to 2 for those external devices.

Answer (score 1):

As @fd0 has pointed out, change the pass value to 2

---

> Why?
>
> **Answer**: *pass* – A number indicating the order in which the `fsck` program
>   will check the devices for errors at boot time; this is **1** for the root
>   file system and either **2** (meaning check after root) or **0** (do not
>   check) for all other devices.